# Javascript decodeURI(Component) malformed uri exception

Tags: javascript, uri, malformed, decodeuricomponent

I entered the following in Chrome's console:

```
decodeURIComponent('a%AFc');
```

Instead of resulting to `a0xAFc`, it caused a URIError exception (malformed uri).

I've heard several excuses why this may be possible, but what I don't understand is **why**?

The `decodeURIComponent()` function in particular is supposed to decode data, not verify the URI.

- [Wikipedia: Percent Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)
- [RFC3986: URI Generic Syntax (2005)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`%AF` is not a character on his own but part of Unicode sequence ([`MACRON - %C2%AF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/af/index.htm)).

`%AF` wasn't produced by `encodeURIComponent` but something like `escape`, so it can be decoded by `unescape`.

What you probably need is `decodeURIComponent('%C2%AF')`

Comment: I made it up after I tried decoding a load of encoded text, failed and noticed it would choke on that particular character. Perhaps `unescape` is what I need.

Comment: @ChristianSciberras `encodeURIComponent()` is usually a better choice because it works with UTF-8. However, `0xAF` on its own is not valid UTF-8-encoded character sequence. This is why your code doesn't work. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: So what if I need to handle ASCII / iso-8859-1 percent-encoded inputs? `unescape` is deprecated, and there is also no `unescapeURI`

Comment: A man like you deserves a special place in heaven. You solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: escape has been Deprecated :(

Answer (score 13):

This may or may not apply to someone else's situation but this is what did it for me so I thought I would share.  I upload and download lots of text files to a custom CMS.
the  **'%' sign in the source code** was wreaking havoc for me.

```
// send to server
content = content.toString().replace(/%/g,'~~pct~~');       // ~~pct~~ <-made up replacement
content = encodeURI(content);

// get back from server / database
content = decodeURI(content);
content = content.toString().replace(/~~pct~~/g,'%');    // globally restore '%'
```

Comment: Really  gr8 hack

Comment: Instead of encoding `%` to `~~pct~~`, encode `%` to `%25`. Then there is nothing to do on the decode side and decodeURI will convert `%25` to `%`.

Comment: You can only decode `%hex` character pairs using try...catch


`content.replace(/(%[0-9a-f]{2})+/gi, a => {try{return decodeURIComponent(a)}catch(e){return a}})`